# Run fat jar as a service on Amazon Linux EC2 instance using Ansible

Tags: java, deployment, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to deploy a [Ninja](http://www.ninjaframework.org/) app to an EC2 Amazon Linux instance using Ansible.

Being a Linux noob and completely new to Ansible, I wonder what the best way would be to start the app via Ansible as a service, rather than just starting a java process, which is what I do for now: `java -jar [path to my jar]`.

This works for now, but it's not idempotent. I.e., I don't think Ansible can figure out a way to only to start the app if it's not already running.

I know Ansible has a [service module](http://docs.ansible.com/service_module.html). Would this be the one to use?

**Update:**

There's a [role called fatjar-service on Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/1292) looking like what I need, but it works only for Ubuntu servers. My server has Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible *service* module is for managing existing OS services. Ansible doesn't have builtin modules that "create" services because there could be many different ways of creating such scripts for various OS/distros. Ansible can ensure that your registered services are enabled and running, but there're no builtin modules to create a service from arbitrary files.

Comment: Yeah, I read that about the service module in the meantime. I'm currently trying out [Stork](https://github.com/fizzed/stork) for automatically creating the artifacts needed for running it as a daemon. I thought there might be an Ansible module for this. Also I will still have to copy the script to init.d, register the service, etc... I was hoping Ansible could abstract that kind of low level stuff away for me.

Comment: No, Ansible can't do that because there are a million different ways of creating scripts for services on various OS/distros. Ansible can ensure that your registered services are enabled and running, but there're no builtin modules to create a service from arbitrary files.

Comment: Thans Mxx. Why don't you post this as an answer? I'd accept it, if nothing else comes up within a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found it best to wrap the application (be it java or node or whatever) using something like Upstart, and use the standard start/stop commands or Ansible module to control the application from that point.

Ansible can easily deploy an upstart wrapper (its a conf file that is placed in /etc/init) alongside the copy of the application file. Once 'installed', start/stop work well.

Substitute Upstart (init) for System V (init.d) or SystemD as desired - there are many other options out there as well of course.